# Is the Projective Real Plane Compact?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I feel like $\Bbb P (\Bbb R^2)$ is compact, but I know that $\Bbb R^2$ is locally compact, therefore it has a one-point compactification. $\Bbb P (\Bbb R^2)$ adds more than one point to the real plane, so I am a little confused. Not sure how to think about this problem.

Comment: Can you think of a compact space $S$ and a continuous surjection from $S$ to the projective plane...? :)

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{RP}^2$ ? This space is not obtained by adding points to the plane, but rather by identifying points in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: RP^2 and P(R^2) are the same thing. You identify points in R^3 but then quotient by the usual equivalence relation so that P(R^2) is just the usual plane with the line at infinity.

Comment: @MatthewLevy I've seen $P(V)$ used to denote the projectivization of $V$, i.e., space of lines in $V$. So some people would think of $P(\Bbb R^2) = \Bbb{RP}^1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using the usual topological description, then the short answer is yes: We can describe the projective plane as the quotient of $S^2$ (the sphere) by the action of $\{\pm 1\} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. As the quotient of a compact space it is automatically compact (continuous image of a compact set).

As a comment, there isn't only one way to compactify a space. One point is minimal, Stone-Cech is in a certain sense maximal, and there are quite often a few in between.

Answer (score 1):

The one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$, that is, smaller than $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$. To get  $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ you add to $\mathbb{R}^2$ the line at infinity which is in fact a projective line, $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{R})$ ( homeomorphic to a circle).

As a side note, there are many compactifications, and the one-point compactification is, for locally compact and non compact, the smallest one. For compact spaces the smallest compactification is the space itself.